# How to prevent `git difftool` from calling another `vimdiff`?

Tags: vim, git

I have `git` configured (like below) to use `vimdiff` as `difftool` and compare another pair of files without prompting as soon as I call `:qa`. It's awesome. The only problem is sometimes there are differences in many files. How do I prevent `git` from running another `vimdiff` instance and continuing the diffs queue?

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
git config --global difftool.prompt false
git config --global alias.d difftool
```

I tried to quit `vim` with a non-zero error code (`:cq`) but it doesn't help.

Would be awesome if the answer worked for both `vim` and `nvim`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a possible solution from [another question, “How do you cancel an external git diff?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2786619/4500798)

Try running:

```
git config --global difftool.trustExitCode true
git config --global mergetool.trustExitCode true
```

and then exiting with the non-zero `:cq`.

Comment: Works for both `vim` and `nvim`! Thanks a lot!